# Python one-liner to replace one word with another word in text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python (through a Linux terminal) to replace the word 'example' in following line of a text file `text_file.txt`:

```
abcdefgh example uvwxyz
```

What I want is:

```
abcdefgh replaced_example uvwxyz
```

Can I do this with a one-liner in Python?

**EDIT:** 
I have a perl one-liner `perl -p -i -e 's#example#replaced_example#' text_file.txt` but I want to do it in Python too

Comment: Can you do this without on-liner?

Comment: Oh wait, did you mean open the file, find the line, replace the text, and rewrite the file- all in one line?

Comment: @Matthew yes I meant open the file, replace text and rewrite all in one line. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: I'm trying to do all this on a Linux terminal. The fewer lines the better

Comment: If you're on Linux and want to do it in one line, is there a reason you can't use `sed`?

Comment: Or if you're doing other processing with it, write a script (python or bash or something)?

Comment: @All I just want an alternative to the command I had in Perl and was wondering if Python had a similar way

Comment: `sed -e 's/example/replace_example/g' text_file.txt` should do the trick.  Any reason why you're insisting on python?

Comment: No reason, I just really like Python :)

Comment: `python -c 'print open("text_file.txt").read().replace("example","replaced_example")'` -- As you can see, this isn't really all that nice (or powerful).

Comment: Yes, I see that. It's pretty clunky. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it:

```
python -c 'print open("text_file.txt").read().replace("example","replaced_example")'
```

But it's rather clunky.  Python's syntax isn't designed to make nice 1-liners (although frequently it works out that way).  Python values clarity above everything else which is one reason you need to import things to get the real powerful tools python has to offer.  Since you need to import things to really leverage the power of python, it doesn't lend to creating simple scripts from the commandline.

I would rather use a tool that is designed for this sort of thing -- e.g. `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/example/replace_example/g' text_file.txt
```

Comment: @prrao -- You can add a `-i` in there to make it operate "in place" -- e.g. `sed -i -e ... file`, though I commonly use `sed -e ... file > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file`

Comment: Yes, I get the picture now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally the fileinput module supports inplace modification just like sed -i

```
-bash-3.2$ python -c '
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("text_file.txt", inplace=True):
    print line.replace("example","replace_example"),
'
```